# ImportError [E048] Can't import language en from spacy.lang

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to run 'en' for Spacy library, which took a lot of debugging to install and finally got it to import in the python library. Next step to load 'en', I spent lot of time debugging why I can't load the files and unable to load in any type of scenarios.

```
# in Python: These libraries are getting loaded. 
import spacy 
import ujson
import en_core_web_sm
```

In Command Line/ linux: I used command below to download 'en' for spacy.

```
python -m spacy download en
```

I got this successful message

```
"You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')."
```

Then I tried to run this and got this error in Python.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

doc = nlp(u'This is a sentence.')

Error: `ImportError: [E048] Can't import language en from spacy.lang.`

What I have tried?:

1) Download the jar file insert into this path: `spacy.util.get_data_path()`

2) Loading the files like this `spacy.load('C:/path_to/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/spacy/data/en')` including jar file name passed in the spaces.

3) Running `java -jar en_core_web_sm-2.0.0a7.tar` and `java -jar en-1.1.0.tar` before running the script. It fails.

Any idea how to solve this? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, try using

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

instead of

```
python -m spacy download en
```

In fact, the 'en' package is just a shortcut for the statistical model 'en_core_web_sm'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded to the latest 3.X version of spacy and faced this error - better to uninstall the previous versions and give a fresh install to the latest version.