# Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ImportError: [E048] Can't import language en from spacy.lang

Tags: python, r, package, spacy, reticulate

Using R 'reticulate' package, I am trying to run a Python code that uses the 'en_core_web_lg' module of Spacy, and I get this error.
I looked around on other user's questions but I didn't overcome the problem yet.
Is anyone able to give some advice?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError \[E048\] Can't import language en from spacy.lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676542/importerror-e048-cant-import-language-en-from-spacy-lang)